# SuiteScript 2.0 setValue not allowed in the current subrecord (Sales Order Record)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to set a value for the sublist '`billingaddress/shippingaddress`'. But the script fail with error "setValue not allowed in the current subrecord". However, I'm able to get the subrecord value.

I need to implement the below **suitescript 1.0 to 2.0** on SALES ORDER record (Client Script).

```
nlapiSetFieldValue('billcity', "TEST");
```

I tried with below.

```
 var currentRecordata = currentRecord.get();
 var subrec = currentRecordata.getSubrecord({
    fieldId: 'billingaddress'
  });    

  subrec.setValue({
    fieldId: 'city',
    value:"TEST"
  });
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> var currentRecordata = currentRecord.get();

Here, `currentRecordata` is a *ReadOnlyRecord* i.e `currentRecord.get()` returns read only record, so you cannot make changes to it.

Also as you said, you are making changes in client script, which entry point (method) do you want to make the said changes? You can get record object in every entry point and this object can be used to read + write.

eg. if you are using `pageInit`, you get currentRecord in scriptContext which is passed by NetSuite itself and you don't have to use `currentRecord.get();`

Further if you want to make changes in view mode, you will have to use `N/record` module to load record, make changes and then save it.

Please check this for further clarifications about [client-script](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4489981198.html) entry points and [CurrentRecord](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4625600928.html) module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using the entry point "beforeLoad".  Can you please let me know how to update the current record without using "currentRecord.get();". Also, will the changes reflects immediately in UI without loading the Page?

Comment: There is no **beforeLoad** in _ClientScript_. If you only want to update record in edit mode, you can use client script's [pageInit](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4410597671.html) method, you will get currentRecord in script context. I don't think NetSuite allows submission of records in beforeLoad as it would result in `Record Has Been Changed` error

Comment: as for reflecting changes, yes if you make any edits in `pageInit` it will reflect immediately on UI, although you should make changes in saveRecord of ClientScript  or `beforeSubmit` in UserEvent

Comment: As per my requirement i need to add One button on existing sales order form and Upon clicking the button update the existing Billing/SHipping address. 


I used below UserEventScript to add Button  on "beforeLoad"
 
        if (context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT || context.type == context.UserEventType.VIEW) {

          context.form.clientScriptModulePath = './clientScripts.js';
          context.form.addButton({
            id: 'custpage_btn',
            label: 'my button',
            functionName: 'validate'
          });
       }

Comment: clientScripts.js - code:
 

  function validate () {
    try {
      var currentRecordata = currentRecord.get();
   var subrec = currentRecordata.getSubrecord({
        fieldId: 'billingaddress'
      });
      var cityValue = subrec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'city'
      });   
   subrec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'city'
  value: "Test"
      });      
    } catch (e) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(e));      
    }

  }

Comment: AFAIK, updating data in real time from client script on button click, does not gives currentRecord, so you can't update it. You can use worklfow instead to add button although that too can't be used to show data in real time on UI.